# Reshape data frame with dcast and melt

Tags: r, reshape

I implemented two functions `reshape_long` and `reshape_wide` (see full working example below) to reshape data frames. 
I created several small examples and the two functions seemed to work properly.

However, using the `reshape_wide` function 
on my real data sets (about 200.000 to 300.000 rows) failed. What happens is set all values for X, Y and Z were set to 1. 
The structure of my real data looks exactly the same as the small example below. After working on it for 2 days I think the 
problem is that the "primary key" (`test_name`, `group_name` and `id`) is only unique in the wide form. After applying the 
`reshape_long` function the primary key is no longer unique. I was wondering, can anyone tell me whether the step 
from `d1 -> reshape_wide -> d2` can work at all because of the non uniqueness of `d1`?

```
library(reshape2) 
library(taRifx) 

reshape_long <- function(data, ids) {      
        # Bring data into long form 
        data_long <- melt(data, id.vars = ids, 
                          variable.name="Data_Points", value.name="value") 
        data_long$value <- as.numeric(data_long$value) 
        # Remove rows were analyte value is NA 
        data_long <- data_long[!is.na(data_long$value), ] 
        # Resort data 
        formula_sort <- as.formula(paste("~", paste(ids, collapse="+"))) 
        data_long <- sort(data_long, f = formula_sort) 
        return(data_long) 
} 

reshape_wide <- function(data, ids) { 
        # Bring data into wide form 
        formula_wide <- as.formula(paste(paste(ids, collapse="+"), 
                                   "~ Data_Points")) 
        data_wide <- dcast(data, formula_wide) 
        # Resort data 
        formula_sort <- as.formula(paste("~", paste(ids, collapse="+"))) 
        data_wide <- sort(data_wide, f = formula_sort) 
        return(data_wide) 
} 

d <- data.frame( 
        test_name = c(rep("Test_A", 6), rep("Test_B", 6)), 
        group_name = c(rep("Group_C", 3), rep("Group_D", 3), 
                       rep("Group_C", 3), rep("Group_D", 3)), 
        id = c("I1", "I2", "I3", "I4", "I5", "I6",                           
               "I1", "I2", "I3", "I7", "I8", "I9"), 
        X = c(NA,NA,1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,7,8,9), 
        Y = as.numeric(10:21), 
        Z = c(NA,22,23,NA,24,NA,25,26,NA,27,28,29) 
) 

d 
d1 <- reshape_long(d, ids=c("test_name", "group_name", "id")) 
d1 
d2 <- reshape_wide(d1, ids=c("test_name", "group_name", "id")) 
d2 

identical(d,d2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written your functions, there is an assumption that the combination of `ids` (`test_name`, `group_name`, and `id` in your example) are unique in the original data.  The easiest way to see this is to take your `d` and duplicate rows.

```
> ddup <- rbind(d,d)
> ddup1 <- reshape_long(ddup, ids=c("test_name", "group_name", "id")) 
> ddup2 <- reshape_wide(ddup1, ids=c("test_name", "group_name", "id")) 
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
> 
> identical(ddup,ddup2) 
[1] FALSE
```

Note that your `reshape_wide` assumes that the `ids` and `Data_Points` together are unique. In this example, they are not. The warning message indicates that `dcast` has used `length` to summarize the multiple values for each combination into a single value.